# select XML nodes by parent node attribute

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm being fed an XML block via a POST. I'd like to parse out a specific `AttributeValue` where the `AttributeId` is equal to `urn:Cisco:uc:1.0:callingnumber`.

Here's the data I get via POST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:context:schema:os">
<Subject SubjectCategory="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:role-id"
DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Issuer="requestor">
<AttributeValue>CISCO:UC:UCMPolicy</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:Cisco:uc:1.0:callingnumber" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
<AttributeValue>89996203741</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:Cisco:uc:1.0:callednumber"
DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
<AttributeValue>95551231234</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:Cisco:uc:1.0:transformedcgpn"
DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
<AttributeValue>89996203741</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:Cisco:uc:1.0:transformedcdpn"
DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
<AttributeValue>95551231234</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Subject>
<Resource>
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id"
DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI">
<AttributeValue>CISCO:UC:VoiceOrVideoCall</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Resource>
<Action>
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id"
DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI">
<AttributeValue>any</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Action>
<Environment>
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:Cisco:uc:1.0:triggerpointtype"
DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">
<AttributeValue>translationpattern</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Environment>
</Request>
```

And what I've tried so far:

```
<?php
$datarequest = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$xmlrequest = simplexml_load_string($datarequest);
$root=$xmlrequest->Subject;


foreach($root->Attribute as $child)
   {
   echo $child->AttributeValue . "<br>";
   }
?>
```

This will return me all the `AttributeValue` results in the `Subject` section of the result. How do I add a conditional criteria into my foreach loop so that it only returns results where `AttributeId="urn:Cisco:uc:1.0:callingnumber`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleXML is rather misleadingly named, as (IMO) it's more complicated than using [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). Here is an implementation of your query using DOMDocument and DOMXPath; XPath is a very easy way to find nodes based on tag names, values, or attributes--much easier that iterating through a document and searching for children, etc.

```
# load the XML into a new DOMDocument object
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );

# create a new DOMXPath object
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
# register the namespace (given in the <Request> element)
$xp->registerNamespace("o", "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:context:schema:os");

# search for AttributeValue nodes with parent Attribute elements 
# with that AttributeId. Note that all the node names have to be prefixed with
# the namespace
$nodes = $xp->query("//o:Attribute[@AttributeId='urn:Cisco:uc:1.0:callingnumber']/o:AttributeValue");

# go through the results and do whatever you want with them
foreach ($nodes as $n) {
    echo $n->nodeName . " node contents: " . $n->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

Output for the document you posted:

```
AttributeValue node contents: 89996203741
```

Comment: I ended up using your approach via DOM I guess the question is what is the advantage / disadvantage of using DOM versus the way @bernie  built it out using 'simplexml_load_string'?

Comment: I think that DOM is easier to use than simplexml--it's more flexible, the documentation is better, and you can use `print_r($node)` to easily view the node contents.

Answer (score 0):

Following on directly from **i alarmed alien**'s answer (which I feel is the best way to approach this), you could use a very similar code approach using xpath however whilst still using SimpleXML.

```
// populate $datarequest (as per question)
$datarequest = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));

// load the XML via SimpleXML
$xmlrequest = simplexml_load_string($datarequest);

// register the name space
$xmlrequest->registerXPathNamespace("o", "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:context:schema:os");

// xpath query to find a particular Attribute node that contains an AttributeId as specified in question
$xpath_result = $xmlrequest->xpath("//o:Attribute[@AttributeId='urn:Cisco:uc:1.0:callingnumber']/o:AttributeValue");

// grab the first result (xpath_result will return an array)
// and cast to a string. Alternatively, you could loop through
// the results if you're expecting more than one match
$result = '';
if (isset($xpath_result[0])) {
    $result = (string)$xpath_result[0];
}

// will output '89996203741'
print $result;
```